# X takes many values using map function Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to make a function

```
isCarmichael :: Int -> Bool
isCarmichael m
  = isPrime m == False && modPow x m m == x
```

in which the x will take all values between 2 and m-1. I was thinking of doing it with the function map but I don't know how it works.

Can anyone explain to me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need the output as a list?, can you give more detail?

Comment: The question is how you combine the expressions where `x` takes those different values.  Do you need them all to be true, or any one of them to be true, or ...?

Comment: From the definition of a carmicheal number from Wikipedia, n is a carmicheal number if for every b, such that 1 < b < n and gcd(b,n) = 1, b^n (mod n) == b. The good thing about haskell is you can translate many mathematical expressions almost verbatim: `\n -> and [ modPow b n n == b | b <- [2..n-1], gcd b n == 1 ]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I deduce correctly, you can do it with a map:

```
isCarmichael :: Int -> Bool
isCarmichael m
  = isPrime m == False && map (\x -> modPow x m m) [2..m-1] == [2..m-1]
```

An alternative way to write `isPrime m == False` is `not (isPrime m)`.

Comment: @user2407038 It might not be the most efficient, but this code works fine if the functions `isPrime` and `modPow` are defined. It also makes sense with the OP's code, although it seems that in both cases `gcd m x == 1` is missing.